# The best way to reset your javascript game after gameover, and how

Tags: javascript, canvas, reset

I am a sort of making a game in javascript, but.. I have a problem.
When you start the html script you see blue canvas with a white rectangle on it. When you mousemove over the white rect the game starts. But now you will go gameover if you go left and right beyond the road. And you go gameover if you hit another car.

Sooo.. My problem now. When you go gameover and you mousemove again over the white rectangle everything is still the same.. It is not reset of course. Now I am asking you guys if you know a good way to reset all the variables, or just something to reset the game.

EDIT: I am specially talking about how to do it, so what commands I should use

Thnx

Here is the game (a sort of) online: http://rekenopjetoekomst.nl/temp/javascript14a.html

This is the javascript part:

```
var autoafb1 = new Image();
var autoafb2 = new Image();
var autoafb3 = new Image();
var autoafb4 = new Image();
var bg = new Image();   
autoafb1.src = "auto2.png";
autoafb2.src = "auto3.png";
autoafb3.src = "auto4.png";
autoafb4.src = "auto5.png";
bg.src = "snelweg.png";

function Canvas(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
    var snelheid = 1

    //var autos = [{"src":autoafb1, "w":100, "h":175, "y":0+175, "x":Math.floor(Math.random()*450-100)+1, "plusafst":0},
        //       {"src":autoafb2, "w":100, "h":175, "y":0+175, "x":Math.floor(Math.random()*450-100)+1, "plusafst":0.5},
            //   {"src":autoafb3, "w":100, "h":175, "y":0+175, "x":Math.floor(Math.random()*450-100)+1, "plusafst":1},
                // {"src":autoafb4, "w":100, "h":175, "y":0+175, "x":Math.floor(Math.random()*450-100)+1, "plusafst":1.5}]

    function Menu() {
        this.x=0, this.y=0, this.w=ctx.canvas.width, this.h=ctx.canvas.height, this.color="blue", this.count=1, this.value="on";
        this.stattX,this.stattY,this.blokx=(ctx.canvas.width*0.5)-(100*0.5), this.bloky=(ctx.canvas.height*0.5)-(100*0.5), this.blokw=100, this.blokh=100;
        this.draw = function(){

            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fillRect(this.blokx,this.bloky,this.blokw,this.blokh);

            if(this.stattX>this.blokx && this.stattX<this.blokx+this.blokw && this.stattY>this.bloky && this.stattY<this.bloky+this.blokh){this.value="off"}

            //this.count = this.count+1;
            //if(this.count>200){this.value="off"}
        }
    }

    function auto() {
        this.h = 175, this.w = 100, this.x = (ctx.canvas.width*0.5)-(this.w*0.5), this.y = (ctx.canvas.height-this.h)-(this.h*0.5), this.color = "Blue", this.afst = 10, this.gameover=0;
        this.draw = function() {
            //ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            //ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
            ctx.drawImage(autoafb1,this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
        }
        this.gameover = function() {
            if(this.x<0){Menu.value="on"}
            if(this.x>ctx.canvas.width-this.w){Menu.value="on"}
            if(this.y<0){this.y=0}
            if(this.y>ctx.canvas.height-this.h){this.y=ctx.canvas.height-this.h}
            for(var i=0; i < tegenauto.autos.length; i++){
                var b = this
                var c = tegenauto.autos[i]
                if(b.x>c.x && b.x<c.x+c.w && b.y>=c.y && b.y<=c.y+c.h){Menu.value="on"}
                if(b.x+b.w>c.x && b.x+b.w<c.x+c.w && b.y>c.y && b.y<c.y+c.h)(Menu.value="on")
                if(b.x>c.x && b.x<c.x+c.w && b.y+b.h>c.y && b.y+b.h<c.y+c.h)(Menu.value="on")
                if(b.x+b.w>c.x && b.x+b.w<c.x+c.w && b.y+b.h>c.y && b.y+b.h<c.y+c.h)(Menu.value="on")
            }
        }
    }

    function background() {
        this.w = ctx.canvas.width, this.h = 1162, this.x = 0, this.y = (this.h*-1)+ctx.canvas.height, this.sec = 1;
        this.draw = function() {
            this.sec = this.sec+1;
            this.afst = 0.001*(this.sec^0.5)
            this.y = this.y+this.afst;
            if(this.y>0){this.y = -1124+ctx.canvas.height};
            ctx.drawImage(bg,this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
            document.getElementById("afst").innerHTML = this.afst;
            //document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = this.sec;
        }
    }

    function tegenauto() {
        this.h = 175, this.w = 100, this.x = 100, this.y = 0-this.h, this.color = "red", this.random=0, this.afst = background.afst, this.sec=1, this.autos = [];
        this.draw = function() {
            //bepalen of een auto
            this.random = Math.floor(Math.random()*8-1)+2
            if(this.random==1){
                //bepalen welke auto
                this.random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                if(this.random==1){this.autos.push({"src":autoafb1, "w":100, "h":175, "y":0-175, "x":Math.floor(Math.random()*450-100)+1, "plusafst":0})}
                if(this.random==2){this.autos.push({"src":autoafb2, "w":100, "h":175, "y":0-175, "x":Math.floor(Math.random()*450-100)+1, "plusafst":0.5})}
                if(this.random==3){this.autos.push({"src":autoafb3, "w":100, "h":175, "y":0-175, "x":Math.floor(Math.random()*350-100)+1, "plusafst":1})}
                if(this.random==4){this.autos.push({"src":autoafb4, "w":100, "h":175, "y":0-175, "x":Math.floor(Math.random()*450-100)+1, "plusafst":1.5})}
            }

            //maken van autos
            for(var i=0; i < this.autos.length; i++){
            var n = this.autos[i];
            n.y=n.y+2+n.plusafst
            ctx.drawImage(n.src,n.x,n.y,n.w,n.h);
            if(n.y > 1000) {this.autos.splice(i,1)}
            }

            //verzet positie


            this.sec = this.sec+1;
            //this.afst = 0.001*(this.sec^0.5)+0.4
            //this.y=this.y+this.afst
            //teken de auto
            //ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            //ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
            //ctx.drawImage(autoafb1,this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
        }
    }

    function gameover() {
        this.draw = function(){
            ctx.font = "60px Arial"
            ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
            ctx.fillText("GAMEOVER!!!",20,100)
            clearInterval(animateInterval);
        }
    }

    var Menu = new Menu();
    var auto = new auto();
    var background = new background();
    var tegenauto = new tegenauto();
    var gameover = new gameover();

    function draw() {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
        //draw

        if(Menu.value=="on"){Menu.draw();}

        if(Menu.value=="off"){
            background.draw();
            auto.draw();
            tegenauto.draw();
            auto.gameover();
        }
        if(auto.gameover==1){gameover.draw();}
        ctx.restore();
    }

    var animateInterval = setInterval(draw,snelheid);

    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
        auto.x = event.clientX-(auto.w*0.5)
        auto.y = event.clientY-(auto.h*0.5)
        Menu.stattX = event.clientX
        Menu.stattY = event.clientY

    });

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        //alert(event.keyCode+" | "+key_press);
        if(event.keyCode == 37) { auto.x -= auto.afst}
        if(event.keyCode == 39) { auto.x += auto.afst}
        if(event.keyCode == 38) { if(auto.y+(auto.h*0.65)>ctx.canvas.height*0.2){auto.y -= auto.afst}}
        if(event.keyCode == 40) { if(auto.y+(auto.h*0.65)<ctx.canvas.height*0.9){auto.y += auto.afst}}
    });
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    Canvas();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a GameOver function that:

1. Resets all your global variables
2. Removes all your EventListeners ( seeing you have two you don't really have to make a list to loop through all of them )
3. Calls the main game function when the player is ready to start again

How to remove your eventListeners? You need to use removeEventListener.

```
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
    canvasMouseOver(event);
});
ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
    canvasMouseOver(event);
});
function canvasMouseover(event){
    auto.x = event.clientX-(auto.w*0.5)
    auto.y = event.clientY-(auto.h*0.5)
    Menu.stattX = event.clientX
    Menu.stattY = event.clientY
}
```

So now you need to reset all your global variables:

```
//Do this initially and call the ResetGlobalVariables at the start to set them properly
//initialize all variables here. Don't set anything to them.
var example1, example2, example3;
ResetGlobalVariables();

function ResetGlobalVariables(){
   //list of all the variables with original attributes here
   example1 = 1;
   example2 = 2;
   example3 = 3;
}
```

Then your game over function will look something like this:

```
function GameOver{
    ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
        canvasMouseOver(event);
    });
    ResetGlobalVariables();
}
```

Comment: oke yes, but how can I reset all my global variables?? and how should I remove the EventListeners. That is what I don`t know...

Comment: @ThomasPereira: far as I know, there is no way to do this gobally and automatically for all variables and event listeners. You have to reset each global variable and unbind each listener one by one...

Comment: Yes you have to do it one by one. However I will attempt to create a list of global variables that you can use. Give me a moment.

Comment: ooh oke.. Yes that is a pity. Thnx Grimbode!

Comment: @ThomasPereira Unfortunately I noted you have global variables throughout your code of different types. It won't be possilbe (that I know of) to store them in any way. You would have to list them in a function like above. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just reload the page with [`location.reload()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp).

> The reload() method does the same as the reload button in your
>   browser.
>
> By default, the reload() method reloads the page from the cache...

```
function gameover() {
    this.draw = function(){
        ctx.font = "60px Arial"
        ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
        ctx.fillText("GAMEOVER!!! Press Enter to retry!",20,100)
        clearInterval(animateInterval);
    }

    isGameOver = true;

}

ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){

    if(isGameOver !== true) {

        auto.x = event.clientX-(auto.w*0.5)
        auto.y = event.clientY-(auto.h*0.5)
        Menu.stattX = event.clientX
        Menu.stattY = event.clientY
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    //alert(event.keyCode+" | "+key_press);

    if(event.keyCode == 13) { location.reload(); }

    if(event.keyCode == 37) { auto.x -= auto.afst}
    if(event.keyCode == 39) { auto.x += auto.afst}
    if(event.keyCode == 38) { if(auto.y+(auto.h*0.65)>ctx.canvas.height*0.2){auto.y -= auto.afst}}
    if(event.keyCode == 40) { if(auto.y+(auto.h*0.65)<ctx.canvas.height*0.9){auto.y += auto.afst}}
});
```

Comment: I am trying to use it, but I don`t know where to place it. It seems like when I place location.reload(). that is just goes on. Like event. But I want it only once to occur.

Comment: @ThomasPereira: See my updated answer. Even if this works, it is more like a hack and I would strongly recommend you to look into guides and documentation for [Object Oriented Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) and rework your code.

Comment: "that is just goes on", and "Like event" are not sentences. When do you want it to reload, when is it reloading, and what's not how you expect? window.reload, while not elegant, should be a decent solution to your current issue, and you can remember to design your next game with resetting in mind (the other person's answer, resetting all variables)

Comment: Yeah I am only 15 from Holland soo my english is not very good.. But  thnx